# implementing maatwebsite headings using foreach

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i want to ask about how to implement multiple heading in maatwebsite

here is may code

```
public function headings(): array

{

    $mapel = DB::table('tb_mapel')->select('nama_mapel')->get()->toArray();

    return [
        ['LEGER'],
        ['', '', 'KI3 (Pengetahuan)'],
        ['NIS', 'Nama Siswa', $mapel],
    ];
}
```

this is the the result of code:

[image]

And this is what i want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the values of nama_mapel, use `pluck()`

Then add the two other elements at the start of the array using `array_unshift()`

```
$mapel = DB::table('tb_mapel')->pluck('nama_mapel')->toArray();
array_unshift($mapel, 'NIS', 'Nama Siswa');

return [
        ['LEGER'],
        ['', '', 'KI3 (Pengetahuan)'],
        $mapel,
    ];
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer @N69S. its right answer.

Comment: i have still get a problem . how to give "nilai" and "predikat" each mapel under cell mapel?

Comment: @SukmoAbadii i dont get your comment! what is  "nilai" and "predikat"  ?

Comment: i have the examle in the picyure [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymWjYrhilxdvfmoa0FgFgsOFwzm9jOEx/view?usp=sharing). i want to make heading like the picture under mapel cell there is "nilai" and "predikat" and auto merge the mapel cell

Comment: @SukmoAbadii that's the subject of another question.